# Hiding/displaying a canvas

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

How do you hide a canvas so it only shows when you want it displayed?

```
self.canvas.config(state='hidden')
```

just gives the error saying you can only use 'disabled' or 'normal'

Comment: The answer depends on how you're showing the widget. Are you using `pack`, `place`, `grid`, or are you embedding it in another widget (either another canvas, or a text widget)?

Comment: pack.  The only time I've seen place used in any examples thus far has been when adding a label to a canvas.

Comment: Actually let me fess a bit further.  The way I had seen it done in other examples, on the map canvas I'm using pack_propagate, but I just went down to the regular pack on the pop up canvas.

Comment: `pack_propagate` has no effect  how how the widget is placed on the screen. It only affects how it reacts to the size of its children.

Answer (score 2):

In the comments you say you are using `pack`. In that case, you can make it hidden by using `pack_forget`.

```
import tkinter as tk

def show():
    canvas.pack()

def hide():
    canvas.pack_forget()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

show_button = tk.Button(root, text="show", command=show)
hide_button = tk.Button(root, text="hide", command=hide)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, background="pink")
show_button.pack(side="top")
hide_button.pack(side="top")
canvas.pack(side="top")

root.mainloop()
```

However, it's usually better to use `grid` in such a case. `pack_forget()` doesn't remember where the widget was, so the next time you call `pack` the widget may end up in a different place. To see an example, move `canvas.pack(side="top")` up two lines, before `show_button.pack(side="top")`

`grid`, on the other hand, has a `grid_remove` method which will remember all of the settings, so that a subsequent call to `grid()` with no  options will put the widget back in the exact same spot.

Comment: So is it better off, if using pack, to place the code for the pop up in the pop up call versus def__init__

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the pop up call".

Comment: Sorry, bad terminology.  I mean the function I go to when the code is supposed to come up and display the pop up.  Should I just place the pop up canvas 'initilization(sp?)' in there versus at the def__init.  I'm thinking that the full code, full placement of the popup is run everytime I go to the function.