# is there a way in python to hide canvas after few second?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to draw 4 spheres that remain on the screen for a few seconds and then disappear. below each sphere a timer appears that shows how many seconds are missing before it disappears. the problem is that what I managed to do in theory works but doesn't appear on screen as it should. 
what am I doing wrong? is there a way to do that?
sorry for maybe awful english but I'm using google translate

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Canvas, BOTH

class Draw(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        canvas = Canvas(self)
        heightpx=Tk.winfo_screenheight(self)
        widthpx=Tk.winfo_screenwidth(self)
        distOrizPx=int(widthpx/4)
        distVertPx=int(heightpx/4)
        radiusPx=50

        self.ball01 = canvas.create_oval(distOrizPx-radiusPx, distVertPx-radiusPx, distOrizPx+radiusPx, distVertPx+radiusPx, fill="blue", width=0)
        self.ball02 = canvas.create_oval(widthpx-distOrizPx-radiusPx, distVertPx-radiusPx, widthpx-distOrizPx+radiusPx, distVertPx+radiusPx, fill="red", width=0)
        self.ball03 = canvas.create_oval(distOrizPx-radiusPx, heightpx-distVertPx-radiusPx, distOrizPx+radiusPx, heightpx-distVertPx+radiusPx, fill="green", width=0)
        self.ball04 = canvas.create_oval(widthpx-distOrizPx-radiusPx, heightpx-distVertPx-radiusPx, widthpx-distOrizPx+radiusPx, heightpx-distVertPx+radiusPx, fill="yellow", width=0)
        canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.timer(distOrizPx-radiusPx, distVertPx+radiusPx) 
        canvas.delete(self.ball01)
        self.timer(widthpx-distOrizPx-radiusPx, distVertPx+radiusPx)
        canvas.delete(self.ball02)
        self.timer(distOrizPx-radiusPx, heightpx-distVertPx+radiusPx)
        canvas.delete(self.ball03)
        self.timer(widthpx-distOrizPx-radiusPx, heightpx-distVertPx+radiusPx)
        canvas.delete(self.ball04)

    def timer(self,posx,posy):
        self.seconds = 3
        self.label= tk.Label(text="%i s" % self.seconds, font="Arial 30")
        self.label.place(x=posx, y=posy)
        self.label.after(1000, func=self.refresh_label())

    def refresh_label(self):
        self.seconds -= 1
        self.label.configure(text="%i s" % self.seconds)
        if self.seconds>-1:
            self.label.after(1000, self.refresh_label)
        elif self.seconds==-1:
            self.label.destroy()

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, master):
        master.title("Ball")
        master.geometry("200x200")
        master.state('zoomed')
        self.master = master
        self.draw = Draw(master)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    master = tk.Tk() 
    pyBall = Ball(master)
    master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding/displaying a canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43639997/hiding-displaying-a-canvas)

Comment: you create and delete balls in the same moment - so you can't see them. You have to use `after()` to run function which will use `delete` to remove element after few seconds.

Comment: `after()` needs function's name without `()` and arguments but you have `()` in `after(1000, func=self.refresh_label())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems.

**First:** you create and destroy balls at the same moment so you can't see balls. You have to use `after()` to run function which will delete ball after few second. You can delete ball in line after `label.destroy()` which removes label after few seconds.

**Second:** you shows 4 balls but you have only one `self.label` and one `self.seconds` and all balls use them. Every ball need own `label` and own `seconds` to count and display time.

I run `timer` with arguments `seconds` and `ball` so every timer has separated variable for time and it knows which ball to delete later.

`Timer` runs `refresh_label` which gets also argument `label` so every `timer` uses own `label`, own `second`, and own `ball`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Canvas, BOTH

class Draw(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.canvas = Canvas(self, bg='red')
        self.canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        heightpx = Tk.winfo_screenheight(self)
        widthpx = Tk.winfo_screenwidth(self)
        distOrizPx = int(widthpx/4)
        distVertPx = int(heightpx/4)
        radiusPx = 50

        self.ball01 = self.canvas.create_oval(distOrizPx-radiusPx, distVertPx-radiusPx, distOrizPx+radiusPx, distVertPx+radiusPx, fill="blue", width=1)
        self.ball02 = self.canvas.create_oval(widthpx-distOrizPx-radiusPx, distVertPx-radiusPx, widthpx-distOrizPx+radiusPx, distVertPx+radiusPx, fill="red", width=0)
        self.ball03 = self.canvas.create_oval(distOrizPx-radiusPx, heightpx-distVertPx-radiusPx, distOrizPx+radiusPx, heightpx-distVertPx+radiusPx, fill="green", width=0)
        self.ball04 = self.canvas.create_oval(widthpx-distOrizPx-radiusPx, heightpx-distVertPx-radiusPx, widthpx-distOrizPx+radiusPx, heightpx-distVertPx+radiusPx, fill="yellow", width=0)

        self.timer(distOrizPx-radiusPx, distVertPx+radiusPx, 17, self.ball01) 
        self.timer(widthpx-distOrizPx-radiusPx, distVertPx+radiusPx, 7, self.ball02) 
        self.timer(distOrizPx-radiusPx, heightpx-distVertPx+radiusPx, 7, self.ball03) 
        self.timer(widthpx-distOrizPx-radiusPx, heightpx-distVertPx+radiusPx, 13, self.ball04) 

    def timer(self, posx, posy, seconds, ball):
        label = tk.Label(self, text="%i s" % seconds, font="Arial 30")
        label.place(x=posx, y=posy)
        label.after(1000, self.refresh_label, label, seconds, ball)

    def refresh_label(self, label, seconds, ball):
        seconds -= 1
        label.configure(text="%i s" % seconds)
        if seconds >= 0:
            label.after(1000, self.refresh_label, label, seconds, ball)
        elif seconds < 0:
            label.destroy()
            self.canvas.delete(ball)

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, master):
        master.title("Ball")
        master.geometry("1200x1200")
        #master.state('zoomed')
        self.master = master
        self.draw = Draw(master)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    master = tk.Tk() 
    pyBall = Ball(master)
    master.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you very much I have solved my problem thanks to you. however there is a small error, `self.canvas = Canvas(self, bg='red')` bg red it prevents us from seeing a sphere being also red

Comment: I used `bg='red'` to check how big is canvas and I forgot to remove it.